# Should I deploy on GAE or AWS?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid, amazon-web-services, nutch

GAE:
+1 Servlet Container ready (+ JVM6)
+2 openid out-of-the-box support /API
-1 JPA2.0 restrictions (inc. - no criteria API)
-2 I cannot use nutch

AWS:
-1 I've to manage a server.
-2 I've to implement OpenID myself.
-3 I cannot use JPA2 with AWS.

The points above illustrate how much/little I know, esp. of AWS. Is there how I could get an AWS Java-ready, JPA2-ready, and OpenID-ready with little-hassle as is the case with GAE.

Comment: Consider voting for JPA2 on GAE: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3079&q=JPA&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: Why can't you use JPA2 with AWS? Surely all you need to use JPA2 is a RDBMS, and you can have that; either use AWS's RDS, or run your own RDBMS on AWS, with the files on EBS. People are doing it with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: can u use AWS RDS with JPA2? With which jpa provider? Any links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 1 limitation in GAE (no SQL support and thus, unbearable JPA restrictions) is gonna fall soon: [Google SQL Service Preview](https://spreadsheets0.google.com/viewform?hl=en&hl=en&formkey=dHBwRmpHV2VicFVVNi1PaFBvUGgydXc6MA&ndplr=1)

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Switching_to_SQLite_for_Your_Local_Datastore

Comment: JPA 2 is finally supported. Much easier to setup, openID support, and less stuff to manage makes it a better choice (when it works).

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Elastic Beanstalk provides you with a managed and scalable Tomcat environment (more app servers may be coming in future) http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Choice between AWS and GAE also depends a lot on your application. The design considerations behind the services are very much different. The goal of GAE is to provide ultimate scalability, but on the other hand eliminate fixed costs (if your application is serving only few customers, running it is very cheap).

GAE maybe be good if your application is lightweight (does not depend on heavy frameworks) and if you can adapt to the datastore limitations. For generic Java applications I would recommend AWS, if the costs associated with Beanstalk and RDS are not too high.

Comment: What about OpenID on AWS/elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: What you said about GAE also applies to AWS.  Most services have a generous free tier.